# Why is this jQuery function failing when called on multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a dialog box and a jQuery function to open / close this. My problem is that after I click 'open' button a second time, something happens and it will not remove the `show` class.

I'm guessing it's because after being called the first time, "it's still there" when I call it a second time. [I have me JS fiddle here to test](http://jsfiddle.net/b877sc20/4/).

What am I doing wrong for this to not work?

```
// JS code
$.fn.sl_dialog = function(params){
    var self = this;

    self.after('<div class="dialog-background"></div>')
    $('.dialog').toggleClass('show');

    $('.dialog .close, .dialog .button.no').on('click', function(){
        $('.dialog-background').remove();
        $('.dialog').toggleClass('show');
    });

    return false;
}


$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
    $('.dialog').sl_dialog();
});
```

Comment: miss a semicolon before `return false`

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it.

Comment: @Oliboy50 that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Why `toggleClass('show')` if your intention is to close the dialog? Why not simply `removeClass('show')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your initialization function (`sl_dialog`) is binding the close handler every time the dialog is initialized, so when you re-open the dialog the event is bound once again.

When closing the dialog the handler is running twice and the `toggleClass('show')` is reverting itself.

Either unbind the handler before applying it:

```
$('.dialog .close, .dialog .button.no').off().on('click', function(){ ...
```

Or use `one()`:

```
$('.dialog .close, .dialog .button.no').one('click', function(){ ...
```

See [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) documentation.

Comment: Thanks Haim. I tried using `off`, but in the wrong place. Using it as you show does not work. But using `one` however does work. Thanks :-D

Comment: aaah, you are using `.off().on()` - I was just testing with `.off()` (I didn't see that)

Answer (score 4):

Move the onclick to outside the function

```
$.fn.sl_dialog = function(params){
    var self = this;
    self.after('<div class="dialog-background"></div>')
    $('.dialog').toggleClass('show');
    return false;
}
$('.dialog .close, .dialog .button.no').on('click', function(){
    $('.dialog-background').remove();
    $('.dialog').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b877sc20/5/)

Comment: Thanks Ling. But the whole point is to have all functions inside the one function so that all I have to do in order to initialize it, is to use `$('.dialog`).dialog();`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the toggleClass to specify addClass removeClass

http://jsfiddle.net/b877sc20/6/

I am not 100% as to why this matters, but it seems to

```
$.fn.sl_dialog = function(params){
    var self = this;

    self.after('<div class="dialog-background"></div>')
    $('.dialog').addClass('show');

    $('.dialog .close, .dialog .button.no').on('click', function(){
        $('.dialog-background').remove();
        $('.dialog').removeClass('show');
    });

    return false;
}


$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
    $('.dialog').sl_dialog();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're registering the click event multiple times as already other people said.

Try adding a flag to detect if you are calling the method for first time so you avoid adding the same event handler more than once.

```
$.fn.sl_dialog = function(params){
    var self = this;

    self.after('<div class="dialog-background"></div>')
    $('.dialog').toggleClass('show');

    if (!self.data('initialized')) {
        $('.dialog .close, .dialog .button.no').on('click', function(){
            $('.dialog-background').remove();
            $('.dialog').toggleClass('show');
        });

        // Add the flag to avoid registering again
        self.data('initialized', true); 
    }

    return false;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b877sc20/7/)

Comment: Thanks Claudio. I followed haim770s suggestion and used `one()` and it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need  all code in function area you have to unbind click event as it is bind every time you click on. Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ycsqequf/

```
$.fn.sl_dialog = function(params){
var self = this;

self.after('<div class="dialog-background"></div>')
$('.dialog').toggleClass('show');

 $( ".dialog .close, .dialog .button.no" ).off( "click" );
$('.dialog .close, .dialog .button.no').on('click', function(){
    $('.dialog-background').remove();
    $('.dialog').toggleClass('show');
})

return false;
}


$('.clickme').on('click', function(){
$('.dialog').sl_dialog();
});
```